# Is "it ring" correct?

Tags: grammar

I saw this sentence in a book and I wonder if it's correct?
"so that you don't hear it ring"
I think it should be "it's ring" or "it rings"

Comment: That isn't a complete sentence. "Put your phone on silent so that you don't hear it ring" would be a valid sentence. You could use _hear it ringing_ instead.

Comment: Agreed that it is not a complete sentence. Also, more context would be helpful. However, going with @KateBunting 's example, "Put your phone on silent so that you don't hear it's (it is) ring," makes no sense. If you wrote, "Put your phone on silent, so that you don't hear it rings," also makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

"... so that you don't hear it ring" is correct. "Ring" here is used as a verb. The writer is saying that if you do whatever, then when "it rings", you won't hear it. (Or realistically, you'll do something to make it not ring at all.)

It would also be valid to say "... so that you won't hear its ring". In that case you're using "ring" as a noun. Note that you use the possessive "its", no apostrophe, not the contraction "it's", which is short for "it is".

You could also simply say, "... so that you won't hear it".

"... so that you won't hear it rings" is not correct. If your intent here is that "rings" is a noun, it's not right because then there are two objects for the same verb. What won't you hear? "It"? Or "Rings"? You could say, "... so that you won't hear its rings". That is, it can have more than one ring and you won't hear any of them. But if we're talking about a telephone or an alarm, we normally use "ring" in the singular. It wouldn't be wrong to use the plural if the thing could have multiple rings, but it would be odd.

If your intent is that "rings" is a verb, you're using the wrong tense. When we have this construction, a verb whose object is a phrase that includes a noun and a verb, we use the simple present form of the verb. Or you can using the -ing form. "You won't hear it ring" or "You won't hear it ringing." If you wanted to you could say "You won't hear when it rings" or "You won't hear if it rings."

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of why "ring" is correct after the apparent subject "it", where you'd expect to see the 3rd person singular "rings".

Comment: @gotube I don't know any answer other than, "That's just not how we say it in English". Perhaps someone else can explain how this is consistent with some other English usage or show historical reasons.

Comment: @gotube - _You_ is the subject, _it_ is the object of the verb _hear_. When we hear or see a person or object doing something, the verb for what they are doing is always in the infinitive form (hear it ring) or the present participle (hear it ringing).

Comment: @KateBunting, That is closer to the answer the OP was likely looking for. Jay's answer didn't address that. What is "it" in relation to "rings" if not its subject?